# Searching for words using phrase SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select

I would like to create a query which would be able to use a the words of a phrase in my "criteria" (like google does)

Example:
My phrase: 'Foo Bar Test'

**My database table:**

|Column|

'Hi Bar'

'Test Bar'

'Hi Foo'

'Nothing here'

'Foo again'

**Result that i'm waiting for:**

|Column|

'Hi Bar'

'Test Bar'

'Hi Foo'

'Foo Again'

Comment: Look up the full text capabilities of SQL Server.

Comment: You could use the "LIKE" operator. For example: WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%Foo%' OR COLUMN LIKE '%Bar%'  OR COLUMN LIKE '%Test%'

Comment: do you want to search in just one column from the table or in all columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any split/parse function can help

```
Declare @YourTable table (YourFieldName varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Hi Bar'),
('Test Ba'),
('Hi Foo'),
('Nothing here'),
('Foo again')

Declare @SearchString varchar(max) = 'Foo Bar Test'

Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Join  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@SearchString,' ') B
   on  Charindex(RetVal,YourFieldName)>0
```

Returns

```
YourFieldName
Hi Foo
Foo again
Hi Bar
Test Ba
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `FULL Text Index` in Sql server. Can be achieved using split string function as well

```
Declare @str varchar(500) = 'Foo Bar Test'

SELECT distinct tc.*
FROM   (VALUES ('Hi Bar' ),
               ('Test Bar' ),
               ('Hi Foo' ),
               ('Nothing here' ),
               ('Foo again' ) ) tc (columnss)
       JOIN [dbo].[Delimitedsplit8k](@str, ' ') f
         ON columnss LIKE '%' + f.Item + '%'
```

To create the split string function check this link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Wouldn't that be an 'And' condition and not what OP wants?

Comment: @sagi - yep completely over looked it